# How to store gas

Tags: gas-laws

For an experiment with an Arduino I want to put some helium in a balloon, and I want to be able to put more gas in it, electronically. My idea was to do this with the help of a small gastube, ( < 1 L) and connect this gastube, with pressurized Helium in it to the balloon, with a valve in between, which I then again can control with the arduino. However, I can't find such a gas tube/ gas cylinder. Any help or comments on how or where to find such a cylinder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your local party supply store will probably rent you a compressed helium cylinder. I have seen helium for balloons sold in the same size tank that is used for propane grills. You would need some kind of pressure regulator between the cylinder and your apparatus.